# A Tolkien-inspired riddle

Tags: riddle

I was inspired by one of [Tolkien's famous riddles](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Riddles_In_The_Dark) from The Hobbit,

> No-legs lay on one-leg,
>   two-legs sat near on three-legs,
>   four-legs got some.

to create a new riddle:

*One-leg took four-legs*
*to a place with no legs,* 
*two-legs came later.*

**Explain what this is describing.**

**Edit.** And here's a hint:

> The one-leg my riddle is referring to can fly. It and its kind don't have wings, but they sometimes have arms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the hint mentioned

> the one-leg is something that can fly.

I thought it could be:

> a rocket.

The four-legs refers to:

> The dog Laika, the first animal in space.

then the place with no legs is

> space, since you're weightless in space and so you effectively have no legs.

two-legs is then:

> Humans, since we went to space later.

Comment: That's correct! What did I mean about one-legs sometimes having arms?

Comment: @BigBlackBox I wasn't sure what you meant about 'arms'. Maybe the side-rockets that fall off when its launched.

Comment: Haha, well I marked your answer as accepted anyway. Nice job! Think about the other meaning of "arms"...

Comment: Don't forget the monkeys

Comment: "Arms" as in "weapons"? Rockets can carry many kinds of explosive (or fissile) ammunition

Comment: @IvanBarreto indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> Evolution

One-leg took four-legs
to a place with no legs,

> A single replicator eventually became 4 nucleotides (the building-blocks, or legs of nucleic acids such as DNA). And took this new replicator to the oceans (at the time, no life-forms there had any literal legs).

two-legs came later.

> We evolved from all of that much later, and we have two legs.

Comment: Nice idea! I think conventional wisdom holds that life began in the ocean (although there are some competing theories), so your interpretation of the first clue needs some work, but it's a creative solution and not bad at all. It's not what I had in mind though, keep trying. If no one gets it I'll probably add a hint tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think one-leg is

> collar

and four-legs is

> the dog.

The place with no legs is

> a park,

and the two-legs is

> the dog owner.

Hence,

> the dog owner taking his/her dog for a walk to a park with its collar. The dog basically is brought by the collar and the owner comes after the dog.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Since my previous answer was wrong, I'll have another go:

> A hole, in golf.

*One-leg took four-legs*

> The club (a single stem/leg) took four tries (legs, or sections of a journey) to get the ball...

*to a place with no legs,*

> The hole.
>  A well-hit ball in golf is also sometimes referred to having legs - *"That's got some legs"*.

*two-legs came later.*

> The human player, having two legs, came along later to collect the ball.

Comment: No, that's not it sorry. Did you see the hint?

Comment: Oh, hadn't seen that hint... back to the drawing board :D

Answer (score 0):

My guesses are:

One-leg took four-legs

> I guess: A Helicopter - assuming *leg* is figurative
>  As the first helicopter designs (Chinese Flying Top or Leonardo's Airscrew) had a single propeller while the first practical working model (early model Skiorosky VS-300s) had four propellers.
>  While the hint: Helicopters fly but have no *wings* but sometimes, like the pictured skiorosky below, they have two "arms" for carrying payloads, to help stabilize, and for other reasons.
>  [image: original Skiorosky vs300 from rotaryforum.com]

to a place with no legs,

> From the 1939 Skiorosky came the jet propelled aircraft of the 1940s which had no propellers or "legs".

two-legs came later.

> Finally in the 1950s to just recently, Tilt-rotor aircraft (like the Marine's V-22 Osprey) have been developed and successfully flown.

Comment: No, that's not it. Also I'm curious which part of a helicopter you are thinking of as corresponding to the arms. Do you have a link to an image of such stabilization or payload-carrying attachments?

Comment: @bigblackbox Added image showing *arms*

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Well, @Dennis_E got the right answer, and the arms were referring to something else...